# Android Orientation

Tags: android

For a game I am trying to create for Android I am looking for a way to use/access the orientation yaw/pitch to move the player left or right.

Does anyone know how to do this, or where to find a tutorial?

Comment: It's not a gyroscope, by the way.  It's a set of accelerometers, which are basically little tiny weights on springs that can measure the deflection of those weights from "zero".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [SensorManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html).

I found a sample [here](http://www.workingfromhere.com/blog/2009/03/30/orientation-sensor-tips-in-android/) and another [here](http://www.anddev.org/accessing_the_accelerometer-t499.html).

There are probably other / better code examples out there - a search for [SensorManager and Accelerometer](http://www.google.com/search?q=sensormanager+accelerometer) should help you out.

Comment: great answer, I'll be using these demos in the coming weeks to do my own sensing app, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I start a library project about android mobile **orientation** that you can get more accurate vector values of orientation, using all available device sensors.

maybe this lib is helpful for you.
[Android-Orientation-Sensor-Library](https://github.com/majidgolshadi/Android-Orientation-Sensor)